# Variable defined as two possible types is "used before being assigned" (TypeScript error)

Tags: typescript

Considering I declare my variable `style` as being potentially of one type or another, how can I solve the TypeScript error I'm getting?

> Variable 'style' is used before being assigned.

```
async myFunction(typography: Typography, valueOnly: Boolean): Promise<Object> {
  let style: object | string;

  try {
    const customFontName = `custom-font-${uuid.v1()}`;
    const customFontFace = new FontFace(customFontName, `url(${typography.custom_font})`);
    const loadedFace = await customFontFace.load();
    ((document as any).fonts as any).add(loadedFace);

    if (valueOnly) {
      style = customFontName;
    } else {
      style = {
        'font-family': customFontName
      };
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

  return style;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anything throws, `style` is uninitialized. That is what the error is pointing out.

If I were you, I'd remove the `try` ... `catch`, and just let the promise resolve with the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You should also assign an empty value to the style in the catch block :

```js
...
 } catch (err) {
    style=''
    console.log(err);
  }
```

Comment: Still getting the error (I hate TypeScript)

Comment: Weird, try to initialize the variable with an empty value